# How to get the video feeds shared by specific friend facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to fetch only video feeds shared by a specific friend what i searched and found is that i can fetch feeds of a specific friend using `uid/feed` but it gives me all the feeds but not only videos.

Can i do that using FQL?

any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fql, just replace "FRIEND_USER_ID":

```
SELECT post_id, type, attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id="FRIEND_USER_ID" AND type=128 LIMIT 150
```

You can tested with Graph API explore, make sure you granted **read_stream** permission

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

This is only for video upload directly to facebook, not included share youtube by LINK

Comment: above will give all the videos of all friends, but i need fetch videos of only one friend (say friend with id 522601313)

Comment: replace the source_id="FRIEND_USER_ID" to source_id='522601313'